# First class patterns in Erlang? (Alternatives)

Tags: erlang, pattern-matching, elixir, first-class

Is there a way to create first-class-like patterns in Erlang? I need to be able to create and pass patterns as args to other functions but I know patterns are not first class in Erlang. I also looked at Elixir but it doesn't seem to offer anything more as far as patterns go.

I was wondering if anyone has come up with a simple solution to this problem. I was thinking of trying to implement something like this:

```
% Instead of using variables, we would just use uppercase atoms which would serve as vars
% A passable pattern
Pattern = {ok, 'Result'}. 

% Custom function to check for matches
match(pattern, {ok, [1,2,3]}). % => true
```

I am new to Erlang so perhaps this is completely unnecessary. Perhaps there is a library that does this sort of thing?

Any advice is greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't know if something exists already that does what you want, but you can easily implement it like this:

```
-module (match).

-compile([export_all]).

-define(MF(S), fun(S) -> true; (_)->false end).


match(F,V) -> F(V).


test() ->
    Pattern = ?MF({ok,_}),
    false = match(Pattern,{error,reason}),
    true = match(Pattern,{ok,[1,2,3]}).
```

Answer (score 3):

You might want to look at [Erlang match specifications](http://www.erlang.org/doc/apps/erts/match_spec.html), which I believe are the sorts of patterns you're asking about. They're used for matching values in [Erlang's tables and databases](http://www.erlang.org/doc/efficiency_guide/tablesDatabases.html) as well as in [Erlang tracing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1954894/using-trace-and-dbg-in-erlang). You might find some inspiration there.

Comment: A problem with the match specifications is that there is no usable functions which check if match specification is valid for a particular input. You have to process them yourself, whereas predicates are very easy to use and fit in the nature of functional programming.

Comment: The patterns used in `ets:select` look interesting. Are there libraries for working with match specs available?

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure I see your entire problem but it seems that a predicate function would suite you well. It's pretty common way to parameterize generic functions with them in a functional language. Take a look at lists functions such as map, foldl, filter.

Answer (score 1):

I ended up using Elixir's macro functionality to implement something similar to Erlang's match specs. The code looks much cleaner(since I am simply defining functions with patterns) and they work very similar to Erlang's match specs.