# MongooseIM module not getting variables from Packet

Tags: php, xmpp, ejabberd, mongoose-im

I wrote the following module for MongooseIM but nothing is posted to the PHP file.

```
start(_Host, _Opt) -> 
    inets:start(),
    ejabberd_hooks:add(user_send_packet, _Host, ?MODULE, fetchPacketData, 50).
stop (_Host) -> 
    ejabberd_hooks:delete(user_send_packet, _Host, ?MODULE, fetchPacketData, 50).
fetchPacketData(_From, _To, Packet) ->
    To = xml:get_tag_attr_s(<<"to">>, Packet),
    httpc:request(post, {"http://example.com/receiver.php",[],
            "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
            lists:concat(["To=",To,"&Type=1","&Body=ABC"])}, [], []).
```

I was able to successfully implement the module after following erszcz's suggestion(Please see below). Below is the code i used. Hope it helps someone else too :)

```
start(Host, _Opts)->
  inets:start(),
  ejabberd_hooks:add(user_send_packet, Host, ?MODULE, sendMessage, 50),
  ok.
stop(Host)->
  ejabberd_hooks:delete(user_send_packet, Host, ?MODULE, sendMessage, 50),
  ok.
sendMessage(_From, _To, Packet) ->
  case xml:get_tag_attr_s(<<"type">>, Packet) of
    <<"chat">> ->
      To = lists:flatten(io_lib:format("~s", [xml:get_tag_attr_s(<<"to">>, Packet)])),
      ** post variables to PHP file using httpc:request **
      ok;
    _ ->
      ok
    end.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`offline_message_hook` is only called when the server is routing a message to a user who is not online. `user_send_packet` is run every time the server receives a stanza from a client. This might explain why the handler is not run, though it depends on how you test. There's [an article with one section describing some hooks in MongooseIM](https://github.com/esl/MongooseIM/wiki/Hooks-and-handlers#selected-hooks-description) available on the official wiki.

As for problems with retrieving packet attributes, either logging the incoming packet for inspection or using `dbg` in the server Erlang shell to trace the actual calls done by your module might be the way to tell what's happening.

---

An example session with `dbg` debugging the problem might look like this:

```
(mongooseim@localhost)1> dbg:tracer().
{ok,<0.570.0>}
(mongooseim@localhost)2> dbg:p(all, call).
{ok,[{matched,mongooseim@localhost,279}]}
(mongooseim@localhost)3> dbg:tpl(mod_test, x).
{ok,[{matched,mongooseim@localhost,5},{saved,x}]}
(mongooseim@localhost)4> (<0.576.0>) call mod_test:fetchPacketData({jid,<<"alice">>,<<"localhost">>,<<"escalus-default-resource">>,<<"alice">>,
     <<"localhost">>,<<"escalus-default-resource">>},{jid,<<"alice">>,<<"localhost">>,<<>>,<<"alice">>,<<"localhost">>,<<>>},{xmlel,<<"presence">>,[{<<"xml:lang">>,<<"en">>}],[]})
(<0.576.0>) exception_from {mod_test,fetchPacketData,3} {error,function_clause}
2015-03-15 11:46:03.028 [error] <0.576.0>@ejabberd_hooks:run1:240 {function_clause,[{lists,thing_to_list,[<<>>],[{file,"lists.erl"},{line,601}]},{lists,flatmap,2,[{file,"lists.erl"},{line,1248}]},{lists,flatmap,2,[{file,"lists.erl"},{line,1248}]},{mod_test,fetchPacketData,3,[{file,"src/mod_test.erl"},{line,15}]},{safely,apply,3,[{file,"src/safely.erl"},{line,19}]},{ejabberd_hooks,run1,3,[{file,"src/ejabberd_hooks.erl"},{line,236}]},{ejabberd_c2s,session_established2,2,[{file,"src/ejabberd_c2s.erl"},{line,1063}]},{p1_fsm_old,handle_msg,10,[{file,"src/p1_fsm_old.erl"},{line,542}]}]}
    Running hook: {user_send_packet,[{jid,<<"alice">>,<<"localhost">>,<<"escalus-default-resource">>,<<"alice">>,<<"localhost">>,<<"escalus-default-resource">>},{jid,<<"alice">>,<<"localhost">>,<<>>,<<"alice">>,<<"localhost">>,<<>>},{xmlel,<<"presence">>,[{<<"xml:lang">>,<<"en">>}],[]}]} 
    Callback: mod_test:fetchPacketData
```

We see that the handler errors out with `function_clause` when calling `lists:thing_to_list(<<>>)`. The empty binary is a result of `xml:get_tag_attr_s/2` when the attribute asked for is not found. `lists:thing_to_list/1` is called to convert each parameter of `lists:concat/1` to a list, but it's not possible to convert an empty binary `<<>>` to a list, hence the crash.

Match on the result of `xml:get_tag_attr_s/2` and craft your logic appropriately to each case: when the attribute is found and when it's not there.

---

> I don't know how to start a module in dbg. I tried what you had shared above and I think you missed the 4th command which could be an example of how to initiate a module.

This is a raw dump of my console without any edits - I did not miss any part.
You don't "start a module in dbg." You simply start a module the usual way and then use `dbg` from the server shell.

What I did was I took your example code, put it into `apps/ejabberd/src/mod_test.erl` file and built a release. After that you can enable the module either in `ejabberd.cfg` of the release (look for the `modules` section and do it similarly as examples there show) or you can start the server in live mode with `mongooseimctl live` and start the module manually with `gen_mod:start_module(<<"localhost">>, mod_test, [])` (where `<<"localhost">>` is just an example XMPP domain - substitute your own suitable domain there).

When the module is running (can be checked with `gen_mod:is_loaded(<<"your-xmpp-domain">>, mod_name_goes_here)`) you have to enable `dbg`. This is shown in the listing I added previously. I won't delve into describing how to use `dbg` as [a very good introduction is already available on StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1954894/using-trace-and-dbg-in-erlang).

---

> an example of how to test if an attribute exists or not

```
case xml:get_tag_attr_s(<<"some-attribute">>, Packet) of
    <<>> ->
        %% attribute does not exist, as get_tag_attr_s returned the default value
        ok;
    <<"some-value">> ->
        %% do something sensible with <<"some-value">>
        ok
end
```

Alternatively, you can use `exml` which is also part of MongooseIM (but not original ejabberd) and is more explicit about not finding the attribute you ask for:

```
case exml_query:attr(Packet, <<"some-attribute">>) of
    undefined ->
        %% not found
        ok;
    <<"some-value">> ->
        %% do something
        ...
end
```

Comment: thank you erszcz. i tried dbg but couldn't solve the problem. can i POST the Packet as it is to the PHP file and check via PHP what is wrong? (i tried this but nothing was posted to PHP)

Comment: The code as you have it now has an error which crashes your function and `httpc:request` never gets called - I described the error above. You can post the whole packet to the PHP app, but you have to serialize it to a string beforehand. Why wasn't your dbg session successful?

Comment: i dont know how to start a module in dbg. i tried what you had shared above and i think you missed the 4th command which could be an example of how to initiate a module.

Comment: also if you could show an example of how to test if an attribute exists or not.

Comment: I edited the original answer addressing your questions.

Comment: thanks erszcz for the detailed explanation. i have successfully implemented the test to check if the attributes exists or not. also, i have used the below method to convert the values to a string and then post it to PHP and it is working fine.  To = lists:flatten(io_lib:format("~s", [xml:get_tag_attr_s(<<"to">>, Packet)])). Thanks a lot for the help. :)