# Only log specific arguments in a call trace when tracing a function using `dbg`?

Tags: erlang

I'm trying to log all calls to a function with `dbg` for debugging (thanks to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1954980/320615) answer). Here's the code:

```
-module(a).
-export([main/0]).

trace_me(_, _, _) ->
  ok.

main() ->
  dbg:start(),
  dbg:tracer(),
  dbg:tpl(a, trace_me, 3, []),
  dbg:p(all, c),
  LargeBinary = binary:copy(<<"foo">>, 10000),
  trace_me(foo, bar, LargeBinary).
```

The problem is that one of the argument is a *really* large binary, and the code above prints the complete binary with every call:

```
1> c(a).
{ok,a}
2> a:main().
(<0.57.0>) call a:trace_me(foo,bar,<<"foofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoo...lots of foos omitted...">>)
ok
```

Is it possible to (without modifying `trace_me/3`):

1. Only print the the first 2 arguments for each call?
2. Print the first 2 arguments + first few bytes of the 3rd argument or just pass the 3rd argument through a custom function before printing?

Comment: have you tried my suggestion with redbug, or do you _really_ need dbg?

Comment: @marco.m sorry I didn't get a chance to update you. I really wanted a solution without adding any new dependencies. Thanks to the video you posted I dived into the implementation of redbug and dbg and wrote a small function that uses the tracer API to do what I want. I will post the solution here as soon as I am able to.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know with `dbg`, but you can use the *very* good and small [`redbug`](https://github.com/massemanet/eper/blob/master/doc/redbug.txt):

```
trace_me(_, _, _) ->
    ok.

do_redbug() ->
    % 1. print arguments as dbg:
    % redbug:start("a:trace_me"),

    % 2. print arity only:
    % redbug:start("a:trace_me", [arity]),

    % 3. Specify the formatting depth:
    redbug:start("a:trace_me", [{print_depth, 10}]),

    LargeBinary = binary:copy(<<"foo">>, 100000),
    trace_me(foo, bar, LargeBinary).
```

Have a look at the (quite terse) redbug documentation in the above link for more options and for how to pass your own printer/formatter function.

Note also that redbug, as opposed to dbg, is safe to use on a production system. Check out this presentation by the redbug author: [Taking the printf out of printf Debugging](http://www.erlang-factory.com/euc2014/mats-cronqvist).

Comment: I ended up using a tiny module I wrote for now: https://gist.github.com/3cc6b76e9a58823c763e3f000ccf4bed. It doesn't handle cases like large binaries inside other things like tuples, but I didn't want to add dependencies to this toy project, and this was good enough. Redbug looks like a more robust solution for debugging production apps. Thank you for the recommendation and also the presentation video link.