# How to print out all data tracked by Erlang dbg

Tags: debugging, erlang, trace

I would like to trace all behavior of Erlang GC using dbg:tracer and print out the tracked events.

```
1> dbg:tracer().
2> dbg:p(self(), [garbage_collection]).
3> my_module:function([Args]).
4> dbg:stop().
5> dbg:show_trace().
...
```

I would like to only trace garbage collection during the execution of `my_module:function/0` function call. Once the function has returned tracing should stop.

Comment: Can you explain the problem with the commands you have shown? Does nothing get printed? Also which version of Erlang are you using?

Comment: I know that I can trace Erlang GC using line 2, but actually I want trace the GC behavior during the execution of line 3. How can I do this ? 

The second question is after stop the trace process (line 4, how can I print out the data tracked ?

Comment: fvarj let me know if my answer fixes your issue.

Comment: @Stratus3D Thank you for all help, it works o/

Answer (score 1):

There may be a better way of doing this, but I would suggest turning off tracing as soon as the function you care about has returned. Something like this should work:

```
1> dbg:tracer().
2> GcOfMyModule = fun() ->
    dbg:p(self(), [garbage_collection]),
    my_module:function([Args]),
    dbg:stop()
end
3> GcOfMyModule().
5> dbg:show_trace().
```

Wrapping the `dbg:p/2`, `my_module:function/1`, and `dbg:stop/0` calls all in one function will mean each function will be executed immediately after the function before it. I got idea originally from the last part of this answer where it takes about automatically stopping a trace after a certain number of events https://stackoverflow.com/a/1954980/1245380.